# I get error message when i open android studio flutter app project

Tags: flutter

I get this message whenever i open a new flutter app project on android studio

Unhandled exception:
Exception: Flutter failed to write to a file at "/Users/Ahmed/.config/flutter/tool_state".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
Try running:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/Ahmed/.config/flutter/tool_state

Comment: Well, have you tried as it suggested? Did you check that the path exists? You are working on a Linux machine, yes?

Comment: Second this ^. Also, run flutter doctor on your machine where you're running your project and make sure everything is working properly.